# What happens to the alarms set via alarm manager by an app, if the app is uninstalled

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have the below code to set up an alarm from my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MY_ALARM_NOTIFICATION");
intent.setClass(myActivity.this, OnAlarmReceive.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                myActivity.this, Integer.parseInt(id),
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar timeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
timeCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
timeCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
timeCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
timeCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
timeCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

Date date = timeCal.getTime();

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

What happens when I remove my application from settings ? Do the alarms remain ?

Answer (score 13):

The events you schedule via `AlarmManager` are removed when the app that scheduled them is uninstalled.

Comment: do you know if it is the same iOS ?

Comment: @tony9099: I am not aware that iOS has `AlarmManager`, `PendingIntent`, etc. You would be better served asking a separate StackOverflow question, tagged with `ios` instead of `android`, to address your concern in iOS-specific terms.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it similar in the case of "app update"? Is the pending intent given to alarm manager removed?

Comment: @Tejas: AFAIK, no.

Comment: I can verify CommonsWare's answer. Application updates DO NOT remove previous pending indents given to AlarmManager. Previously scheduled repeating alarms are fired normally, after an app update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments guys! This should be in google's official docs of AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the reminders to persist after uninstall, you will need to add them to the Google Calendar of the user (or create a calendar) with an intent

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, reminderDateTime.getMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, reminderDateTime.getMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "TITLE"
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, eventDescription)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, new int[]{CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALARM, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT})
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
```