# State of Alarm when App is reinstalled

Tags: android-alarms, android-install-apk

Hi I have an app that sets an alarm to do a specific operation when the alarm is triggered.

In case if I re-install the app, what will happen to the Alarm that was set previously?
Will it still be active? or will it be killed due to re-installation.

Will there be any change in behavior if the app is a System app? I mean will the alarm be active even in the case of re-installation for System apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465314/what-happens-to-the-alarms-set-via-alarm-manager-by-an-app-if-the-app-is-uninst) question.

The alarms set by your applications are removed when your app is uninstalled. I believe the same it true for system apps (have never tried though).

To make sure that you have alarms are scheduled correctly you can do the following:

1. On application start check whether alarms exist and set them if necessary.
2. Subscribe to `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent and do #1 in your receiver.